# Using pivot does not return lates values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using this Oracle query to get latest values which are stored in rows and separated by PROPERTY_ID column:

```
SELECT *   FROM (SELECT S.FILE_CODE,
               SP.SUBSCRIBER_ID,
               NVL (
                   TO_CHAR (NVL (RC.FIRST_NAME, '') + NVL (RC.LAST_NAME, '')),
                   LC.LEGAL_NAME)    CUSTOMER_NAME,
               PROPERTY_ID,
               PROPERTY_CONTENT--,SP.AUTO_ID
          FROM CUSTOMERS_TCI.A_SUBSCRIBER_PROPERTIES  SP
               INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS_TCI.SUBSCRIBERS S
                   ON S.SUBSCRIBER_ID = SP.SUBSCRIBER_ID
               INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS_TCI.CUSTOMERS_INFO CI
                   ON CI.CUSTOMER_ID = S.CUSTOMER_ID
               LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERS_TCI.REAL_CUSTOMER RC
                   ON RC.CUSTOMER_ID = CI.CUSTOMER_ID
               LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERS_TCI.LEGAL_CUSTOMER LC
                   ON LC.CUSTOMER_ID = CI.CUSTOMER_ID
         WHERE PROPERTY_ID IN (277,
                               289,
                               290,
                               291) AND SP.PROVINCE_ID = 22)
           PIVOT (
                 MAX(PROPERTY_CONTENT)
                 FOR PROPERTY_ID
                 IN (277 AS GRAPH,
                    289 AS GRAPH_REGISTRATION_DATE,
                    290 AS GRAPH_YEAR,
                    291 AS GRAPH_MONTH))  WHERE GRAPH_YEAR = '1402' AND FILE_CODE = '658051' ORDER BY CUSTOMER_NAME;
```

I'm using pivot to convert rows to columns, so I have result like this:
[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkMFZ.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkMFZ.png)

but it is not correct, it does not show last_value for column PROPERTY_CONTENT, I have column AUTO_ID as primary key for table CUSTOMERS_TCI.A_SUBSCRIBER_PROPERTIES by the way.

this is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS_TCI.A_SUBSCRIBER_PROPERTIES
(
  AUTO_ID                 NUMBER(20) PK,          
  SUBSCRIBER_PROPERTY_ID  NUMBER(20),
  SUBSCRIBER_ID           NUMBER(15),
  PROPERTY_ID             NUMBER(20),
  PROPERTY_CONTENT        VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE),  
  PROVINCE_ID             NUMBER(4),
 
)
```

here is the insert query to reproduce table:

```
INSERT INTO A_SUBSCRIBER_PROPERTIES(AUTO_ID, SUBSCRIBER_PROPERTY_ID, SUBSCRIBER_ID, PROPERTY_ID, PROPERTY_CONTENT, PROVINCE_ID, FILE_CODE) 
VALUES 
(8, 1000, 321, 277, '20', 22, 741),
(7, 1001, 321, 289, '2/14/2024', 22, 741),
(6, 1002, 321, 290, '2024', 22, 741),
(5, 1003, 321, 291, '2', 22, 741),
(4, 1004, 321, 277, '30', 22, 742),
(3, 1005, 321, 289, '1/14/2024', 22, 742),
(2, 1006, 321, 290, '2024', 22, 742),
(1, 1007, 321, 291, '1', 22, 742);
```

for example: I have table like this:

[image: table data]

for FILE_CODE = 741 my query should return:

[image: final result]

but return this:
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; an English (not code) explanation of the logic that you are trying to implement; the actual output from your query for that sample data; and the expected output. At the moment the question is difficult (impossible) to answer because we have no way of replicating the problem.

Comment: `NVL(RC.FIRST_NAME, '')` is pointless as, in Oracle, `''` and `NULL` are identical so you are doing `NVL(RC.FIRST_NAME, NULL)` which is the same as just using `RC.FIRST_NAME`.

Comment: `RC.FIRST_NAME + RC.LAST_NAME` should not be valid (assuming your names are non-numeric strings)  as `+` is the addition operator (for numbers), not the string concatenation operator (which is `||`).

Comment: You have edited the question to include the DDL statement for one table but have not included the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the other four tables you `SELECT` from and have not included any `INSERT` statements for sample data so we cannot run your query. We also do not know what the expected ("correct") output would look like for that sample data.

Comment: DO **NOT** post images of data. Post the `INSERT` statements so that volunteers can copy-paste and execute your statements an build the table without having to transcribe data from your images (which wastes everyone's time, is not accessible and is error prone).

Comment: How can I attach excel file? Other 4 tables are optional by the way and could be ignored

Comment: You cannot (and should not) attach files, [edit] the question and use text (and please don't just post numbers/text as tables because that is only marginally better than posting images as we still have to recreate the DML statements from that table, instead take the time and post the `INSERT` statements to recreate the data).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using this Oracle query to get latest values which are stored in rows and separated by PROPERTY_ID column

Your sample data has no way of telling what the "latest" value is as there is no timestamp associated with any of the rows and you have two rows with the `property_id` of `277` so when you ask for the `MAX`imum then it finds the greater of those two values.

If you want to have a "latest" then you need some logic to determine what rows you want.

- Is it the minimum `file_code`?
- Is it looking at the `property_id` of `289` and finding the latest date?

If it is the former and you want the minimum `file_code` then:

```sql
SELECT file_code,
       subscriber_id,
       customer_name,
       property_id,
       property_content
FROM   (
  SELECT S.FILE_CODE,
         SP.SUBSCRIBER_ID,
         COALESCE(RC.FIRST_NAME || RC.LAST_NAME, LC.LEGAL_NAME) AS CUSTOMER_NAME,
         PROPERTY_ID,
         PROPERTY_CONTENT,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY subscriber_id ORDER BY file_code) AS rnk
  FROM   CUSTOMERS_TCI.A_SUBSCRIBER_PROPERTIES  SP
         INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS_TCI.SUBSCRIBERS S
         ON S.SUBSCRIBER_ID = SP.SUBSCRIBER_ID
         INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS_TCI.CUSTOMERS_INFO CI
         ON CI.CUSTOMER_ID = S.CUSTOMER_ID
         LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERS_TCI.REAL_CUSTOMER RC
         ON RC.CUSTOMER_ID = CI.CUSTOMER_ID
         LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERS_TCI.LEGAL_CUSTOMER LC
         ON LC.CUSTOMER_ID = CI.CUSTOMER_ID
)
WHERE  rnk = 1
```

and then `PIVOT` on the output from that.

If it is the later and you want the latest `289` content then include `file_code` in the inner `SELECT` so that when you `PIVOT` the columns are pivoted for each `subscriber_id`/`file_code` and then apply the `ROW_NUMBER` (or `RANK`) analytic function to filter to return only the pivoted row with the latest `graph_registration_date` for each `subscriber_id`.

Something like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT p.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY subscriber_id
           ORDER BY TO_DATE(GRAPH_REGISTRATION_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT S.FILE_CODE,
           SP.SUBSCRIBER_ID,
           COALESCE(RC.FIRST_NAME || RC.LAST_NAME, LC.LEGAL_NAME) AS CUSTOMER_NAME,
           PROPERTY_ID,
           PROPERTY_CONTENT
    FROM   CUSTOMERS_TCI.A_SUBSCRIBER_PROPERTIES  SP
           INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS_TCI.SUBSCRIBERS S
           ON S.SUBSCRIBER_ID = SP.SUBSCRIBER_ID
           INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS_TCI.CUSTOMERS_INFO CI
           ON CI.CUSTOMER_ID = S.CUSTOMER_ID
           LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERS_TCI.REAL_CUSTOMER RC
           ON RC.CUSTOMER_ID = CI.CUSTOMER_ID
           LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERS_TCI.LEGAL_CUSTOMER LC
           ON LC.CUSTOMER_ID = CI.CUSTOMER_ID
    WHERE  PROPERTY_ID IN (277, 289, 290, 291)
    AND    SP.PROVINCE_ID = 22
  )
  PIVOT (
    MAX(PROPERTY_CONTENT)
    FOR PROPERTY_ID IN (
      277 AS GRAPH,
      289 AS GRAPH_REGISTRATION_DATE,
      290 AS GRAPH_YEAR,
      291 AS GRAPH_MONTH
    )
  ) p
  WHERE GRAPH_YEAR = '1402'
)
WHERE  rn = 1
--AND   FILE_CODE = '658051'
ORDER BY CUSTOMER_NAME;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mbHf_I3q)

Comment: it could be AUTO_ID column. MAX AUTO_ID column

Comment: @BehnamFaghih `MAX(auto_id)` is `8` which is a single property so your pivot would not work. If you took the `MAX(auto_id)` for each `property_id`/`subscriber_id` pair then you may find that you are getting values for different `file_code`. We **CANNOT** tell you how to implement this as this is something defined in the business logic that you and your company understand and people on StackOverflow have zero knowledge of. **YOU** need to define how the logic should be implemented to meet your business needs.